# Transferring Time-Derivative Inside Spacial-Norms Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

A colleague and I have come across what looks to be a very easy inequality to prove, but we are stumped. Anyway, assuming that $u$ is in all the appropriate spaces, does anyone have any idea how to prove the following inequality? 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\|u(t,\cdot)\| \le \|u_t(t,\cdot)\|?$$ 
In this case the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is in space not time. My first attempt was to look at
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \|u\|^2 = (u_t,u) \le \|u_t\|\, \|u\|,$$
but this didn't seem to go anywhere. Applying Young's inequality didn't make things better, since
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \|u\|^2 \le \frac{1}{\epsilon} \|u_t\|^2 + \epsilon \|u\|^2,$$
looks like a dead end and would produce a constant that is most likely not $1$ and things would remain squared.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by $||u||$ on your second line.

Comment: This doesn't help, since it cannot be transferred inside the derivative. Also, there is no guarantee that $\|u\| \ne 0$. Even if you could do this it would leave a constant.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. Isn't $||u||\frac{\partial ||u||}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ||u||^2}{\partial t}$, and if $||u|| = 0$, it's trivial?

Comment: Yes, this would be correct. I guess it is one of those things where you miss something right in front of your face.